# Scraper yields no results

Tags: python, python-requests

I am very new to python (this is my first Python project, in fact) and I am having a bit of trouble writing this web scraper. I used a [tutorial](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/) to figure this out, but the code is yielding no results. I would really appreciate some help.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://openbook.sfgov.org/openbooks/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=/content/folder%5B%40name%3D%27Reports%27%5D/report%5B%40name%3D%27Budget%27%5D&ui.name=20Budget&run.outputFormat=&run.prompt=false')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will find the table headers:
categories = tree.xpath('//*[@id="rt_NS_"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]')
# This will find the budgets
category_budget = tree.xpath('//*[@id="rt_NS_"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span[1]')

print 'Cateogries: ', categories
print 'Budget: ', category_budget
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like contents of `table id="rt_NS_"` are being generated by JavaScript.

In that case `requests` won't help you.

```
page = requests.get('http://openbook.sfgov.org/openbooks/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=/content/folder%5B%40name%3D%27Reports%27%5D/report%5B%40name%3D%27Budget%27%5D&ui.name=20Budget&run.outputFormat=&run.prompt=false')

ctx = page.content
if "id=\"rt_NS_\"" in ctx:
    print "Found!"
else:
    print "Not Found!"

Not Found!
```

You'll need to use other approach. [Selenium with python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) could be an option.

Comment: That is unfortunate, but thank you for looking Samuel! It appears that this is a [relevant post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738920/python-selenium-scraping-webpage-javascript-table). This should help put me in the right direction. You rock!